# Have the view cube not disapear when pressing g

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a way to have the view cube not disappear when pressing G?
I mean this one

[image]

as a beginner I'm having problems remembering which color is which axis and having it there when pressing G would help when locking things to an axis.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, if you pressed G (to move the object) and then X (choosing the X axis movement), and noticed that you actually want to move the object along the Y axis, you can simply press Y while moving, and the movement will be locked to the Y axis from that moment on.

Comment: I think it's not possible, but if you hit g, then hold the middle mouse button, you can choose the axis by moving the mouse its direction.

Comment: It's easier to remember if you think of it as X,Y,Z = R,G,B.  You can also use Shift+Space then G which will show the gimbal.